# Windows phone WNS notification navigation to specific page

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

It is Windows runtime, Windows phone targeted project.

I'm using Azure and Azure notification hubs. So my question is does anyone how how to navigate to some specific page and send parameters like id.

Here is my toast template as here described in string:

```
   var toast = @"<toast><visual><binding template=""ToastText01""><text id=""1"">" + datatoshow + "</text></binding></visual></toast>";
```

Should i user raw or other notification type. Thanks a lot.

This link wasn't helpful for my problem:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761494.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better document page for this is [Quickstart: Sending a toast notification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh868254(v=win.10).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#specify_app_launch_parameters)'s Specify launch parameters segment. The reference is in the [toast element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/br230846.aspx) definition.

Set the launch attribute of the toast element to a string that'll be passed to the app when it is activated. The app can then switch based on that string.

```
var toast = @"<toast launch=""?page=foo&id=7""><visual><binding template=""ToastText01""><text id=""1"">" + datatoshow + "</text></binding></visual></toast>";
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, i also found some nice stuff here : https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/03/25/how-to-pass-arguments-to-an-app-activated-by-a-toast-notification/